# Выборка и вывод из двух таблиц

Tags: php

Может кто подскажет как правильно это сделать?
Попробовал по принципу zar.name_zar и products.user, но вот дублирующие записи по этому принципу к сожалению. 
Что бы было понятно, мне нужно вывести список из products с совпадение из zar:
$resultA - таблица products и resultB - таблица zar.

```
 if($resultA['ID'] == $resultB['id_zar']){$oplata = $resultB['price_zar'];}
 else{$oplata = "Не оплачено";}
```

Вот полный код:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$sqlA = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE user LIKE '%".$rname."%' ORDER BY ID DESC", $link);
$sqlB = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `zar` WHERE  name_zar LIKE '%".$rname."%' ", $link);


   $resultA=mysql_fetch_array($sqlA);
    $resultB=mysql_fetch_array($sqlB);

while ($resultA  .$resultB) {

   if($resultA['ID'] == $resultB['id_zar']){$oplata = $resultB['price_zar'];}
 else{$oplata = "Не оплачено";} 

    $oplata;


    echo 

    '<tr>'.
 '<td><a href="/id.php?red_id='.$result['ID'].'"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i></a></td>'.
 '<td>'.$result['ID'].''.
 '<td>'.$result['data'].'</td>'.

 '<td>'.$result['Tech'].'</td>'.

 '<td>'.$result['status'].'</td>'.

 '<td>'.$result['end'].'</td>'.

  '<td>'.$oplata.'</td>'.


 '</tr>'
 ;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Объедините ваши запросы в один

```
$sql = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM `products` AS `p`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `zar` AS `z` ON z.id_zar = p.ID
    WHERE p.user LIKE '%".$rname."%' 
    ORDER BY p.ID DESC");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    echo 
      '<tr>'.
        '<td>
           <a href="/id.php?red_id='.$result['ID'].'">
             <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
           </a>
        </td>'.
       '<td>'.$result['ID'].''.
       '<td>'.$result['data'].'</td>'.
       '<td>'.$result['Tech'].'</td>'.
       '<td>'.$result['status'].'</td>'.
       '<td>'.$result['end'].'</td>'.
       '<td>'.$result['price_zar'].'</td>'.    
     '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Выводит не правильно по порядку выводя price_zar и дублируются записи, как и говорил что так пробывал уже..

Comment: https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/cb46c128-f48c-458b-a4b8-fa59dee7459b.png

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев обновил запрос. Передела связь на ID = id_zar

Comment: При таком запросе вывод не всего списка products с участием конкретного пользователя, а только если в zar есть запись. Такая вот печалька, что нужен весь список

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев т.е в таблице `zar` может не быть информации для таблицы `products`.  правильно?

Comment: Именно так . Для большей ясности скажу, что таблица products это список заявок, а в таблице zar информация о переводе мастеру зарплаты за заявку. Если например в  zar есть запись то деньги зачислены и id_zar  индентична ID из products, так как записи не существует пока деньги не переведены и от туда переменная $oplata через если. Как то так

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев обновил код. В данном случае используется оператор `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Огромное, человеческое спасибо! код работает как и хотел и самое главное, что узнал и прочитал про JOIN.. В дальейшем это очень здорово поможет в понимании. Очень круто, что  помог, сам бы я не допёр до этого

Comment: @ВикторМуравьев не за что. В след. раз в вопросе расписывайте все и желательно указывать какой хотите получить результат